# DataColumn.Expression Power

Tags: ado.net, datacolumn

the following code

```
Dim dc = New DataColumn(name, GetType(Double), "[col1] ^ [col2]")
```

produces the following error:

```
The expression contains unsupported operator '^'.
```

Is this right, is the power operand not support in datacolumn expressions???

Anyone have an idea how i'd write this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is not supported.

You could use [RowChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanging(VS.71).aspx) event of DataTable to set the value of the new column using c#.

Comment: Yup, i already implemented a manual update but this sure feels like a hack to me.  Also, on small tables it's OK, but updating 100000+ records takes a big hit...

Comment: Using the RowChanging event causes a System.Data.InRowChangingEventException to be thrown. Use RowChanged instead and only change it when needed (or else you end up with a stack overflow when it calls itself recursively).